# 0403-005 Cannot create the specified file

Tags: unix, db2, aix

anyone here who knows why upon doing shell script **0403-005 Cannot create the specified file** this error occur?

On my script whenever I use the absolute path it doesn't encounter the same error, however I need the script for multiple servers with different home directory that's why I am trying to use either the **~** or **$HOME** but the error always pops out.

Comment: There's a little bug in your script.

Comment: What’s the exact command you use? What’s the shell specified in the script?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have found the answer to my own question already. It's because VAR='~/something.txt' doesn't work with AIX. Instead I used VAR=~/something.txt anyways. Thank you guys